# Undefined method "errors"... But there are ERRORS

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation

I am doing a basic validation for a bank entry and am trying to display the errors on submit.  Here is my validation and html.

controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @guestbook_entries = GuestbookEntry.all
    @guestbook_entry = GuestbookEntry.new
    render "welcome"
  end
end


class GuestbookEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :body, presence: :true
end
```

This is my html:

```
<% form_for @guestbook_entry do |f| %>                                                                                   
  <% if f.errors.any? %>                                                                                
    <% f.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>                                                                                         
      <li><%= m %></li>                                                                                          
    <% end %>                                                                                                   
  <% end %>                                                                                 
  <%= f.label :body, "Guestbook Entry:" %>                                                                                     
  <%= f.text_area :body %>                                                                                                         
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>                                                                                     
<% end %>
```

[image: new error]

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: Looks like a typo. It should be `@guestbook_entry.errors`, but the error in the screenshot shows `@guestbook_entries.errors`.

Comment: Seems like you posted the wrong view page code.

Comment: added my controller and updated some code.  New/better? error.

Comment: `errors` is not a method on the form object. It is on the model. You need to write `@guestbook_entry.errors` not `f.errors`. Refer to the official guide on displaying validation errors in views: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views